# Lebesgue Space/Bochner Space interpolation Theorem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces, bochner-spaces

I need the embedding, for $I\subset\mathbb{R}$ is a bounded intervall and $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is a bounded domain,

$$L^{q_1}(I;L^{p_1}(\Omega))\cap L^{q_2}(I;L^{p_2}(\Omega))\hookrightarrow L^q(I;L^p(\Omega))$$

I know for $f \in L^{p_1}(\Omega) \cap L^{p_2}(\Omega)$ and $1\leq q_2\leq q\leq q_1<\infty$, it holds $f \in L^q(\Omega)$
and it holds the interpolation inequality

$$|f|_p \leq |f|_{p_1}^{1-\theta}|f|_{p_2}^\theta$$

with $\tfrac{1}{p} =: \tfrac{1-\theta}{p_1} + \tfrac{\theta}{p_2}$ or $\theta:= \tfrac{p_2}{p}\tfrac{p_1-p}{p_1-p_2}$ for $p_2 \neq p_1$.

This holds two times but how can I combine those to get my claim?

I think I need something like (for $I=(0,T)$)

$$||f||_{L^q(0,T;L^p(\Omega))}\leq||f||^{1-\theta}_{L^{q_1}(0,T;L^{p_1}(\Omega))}||f||^{\theta}_{L^{q_2}(0,T;L^{p_2}(\Omega))}$$

So I started with

$$||f||^{}_{L^q(0,T;L^p(\Omega))}=||(||f||_{L^p(\Omega)})||_{L^q(0,T)}\leq||(||f||^{1-\theta}_{L^{p_1}(\Omega)}||f||^{\theta}_{L^{p_2}(\Omega)})||^{}_{L^{q}(0,T)}$$

$$\leq||(||f||^{1-\theta}_{L^{p_1}(\Omega)})||^{}_{L^{q_1}(0,T)}\cdot||(||f||^{\theta}_{L^{p_2}(\Omega)})||^{}_{L^{q_2}(0,T)}.\tag{1}\label{1}$$

Now the big question is: Does the following inequality hold?

$$\eqref{1}\leq||f||^{1-\theta}_{L^{q_1}(0,T;L^{p_1}(\Omega))}||f||^{\theta}_{L^{q_2}(0,T;L^{p_2}(\Omega))}$$

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that the answer is just an application of Hölder's inequality away:

Let me use $|.|_p$ for the norme in $L^p(\Omega)$ and $\|.\|_q$ for the norm in $L^q(I)$. Set $f_j:=|f|_{p_j}$ and note that by assumption $f_j\in L^{q_j}(I)$. Hence using [Lyapunov's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality#Interpolation)
$$
\|f\|_{L^q(I;L^p(\Omega))}=\| |f|_p \|_q \le \| f_1^{1-\theta} f_2^\theta \|_q
$$
as you already had. Now using the generalized [Hölder inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality#Generalization_of_H%C3%B6lder's_inequality) with
$$
\frac{1}{q} = \frac{1-\theta}{q_1} + \frac{\theta}{q_2}
$$
we obtain
$$
\|f_1^{1-\theta} f_2^\theta \|_q \le \|f_1^{1-\theta} \|_{q_1/(1-\theta)} \|f_2^\theta \|_{q_2/\theta} = \|f_1\|_{q_1}^{1-\theta} \|f_2\|_{q_2}^\theta,
$$
which is the desired estimate.