# Interpolation in Lebesgue-Bochner $L^p-L^q$ spaces.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, lp-spaces, interpolation, bochner-spaces

Consider $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ open and bounded, $I$ some bounded interval of $\mathbb{R}$. Let $2^\ast := \frac{2n}{n-2}$ (the critical Sobolev exponent).

Let $u \in L^{\infty}(I; L^2(\Omega)) \cap L^2(I; L^{2^\ast}(\Omega))$. Let $(p,q)$ such that $$\frac{2}{p} + \frac{n}{q} = \frac{n}{2}.$$
How can I control the norm of $u$ in $L^p(I; L^q(\Omega))$ with the norms in $L^{\infty}(I; L^2(\Omega))$ and $L^2(I; L^{2^\ast}(\Omega))$?

I am aware of [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1698824/lebesgue-space-bochner-space-interpolation-theorem) in this direction but the relation between $p$ and $q$ is not the same here.

This appears in these [notes](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/vasseur/documents/preprints/DGPekin.pdf), at the bottom of page 17.

Comment: (I think there is a typo, it should be $n/2$ instead of $2/n$).

Comment: You're right, this is fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the post you linked basically answers your question. You simply need to rewrite
$$ \frac{1}{p}= \frac{(1-\theta)}{\infty}+ \frac{\theta}{2},\quad \frac{ 1}{q}= \frac{(1-\theta)}{2}+ \frac{\theta}{2^*}$$ with the same number $\theta\in[0,1]$. This can be done since the pairs $(p_1,q_1)=(\infty,2)$ and $(p_2,q_2)=(2,2*)$ satisfy the same relation of $(p,q)$, that is, $$ \frac{ 2}{p_j}+ \frac{ n}{q_j}= \frac{ n}{2}, $$ $j=1,2$. Once you do this, you simply apply the arguments in the linked post and you are done.